# Can we setup a common Glance for multiple Openstack setups?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have two Grizzly setups pointing to two different Glance services.

Now my questions are:

1. Is there any possibility to setup this kind of environment?
2. When we create a snapshot of server in any setup then it should be created in the common Glance?
3. Is there any option from nova to specify that the image should be picked from specific Glance?
4. Can we migrate a VM from one Grizzly setup to other?

Pointers on it will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/openstack-compute/admin/content/replicating-images.html

Comment: Fundamentally the problem is glance can currently only backend to one keystone environment.  So no you couldn't easily.  This will change as better domain structures are implemented in keystone.  And a more federated keystone emerges.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer like has been mentioned is "No".

We are using a somewhat complicated solution to this same problem:

1. Setup each glance host to mount an NFS share (/images)
2. For each image file link /var/lib/glance/images/* to /images/* (for each.. ln -s)
3. Hack the glance db to make it look like images were created on this glance server:

`mysql -h localhost -ppassword -u glance glance -ss -e 'delete from image_locations'`

`mysql -h localhost -ppassword -u glance glance -ss -e 'delete from images'`

`mysql -h localhost -ppassword -u glance glance -ss -e 'insert into images (id,name,size,status,is_public,created_at,updated_at,deleted,disk_format,container_format,checksum,min_disk,min_ram,protected) values("b5ddc4ff-f370-471b-a1e4-aab8441b1a70","precise-server-agent-ready.img",1222836224,"active",1,"2013-04-24 20:16:23","2013-04-24 20:17:49",0,"qcow2","bare","450a6ae6ef4e973bbc436f844fd3d6ab",2,0,0);'`

The checksum is an md5sum of the image. The rest are reasonably self explanatory.
For Havana, all images have mindisk specification to match stronger flavor constraints (no more disk size 0 allowed by nova). For Grizzly mindisk can be zero.